# Can Agda compile faster in batch mode?

Tags: compilation, incremental-build, agda

When I compile an Agda program that uses the standard library, the compiler spends a long time printing out lines such as:

```
Skipping Relation.Binary.Consequences (/home/owen/install/lib-0.6/src/Relation/Binary/Consequences.agdai).
Skipping Relation.Binary.Indexed.Core (/home/owen/install/lib-0.6/src/Relation/Binary/Indexed/Core.agdai).
Skipping Relation.Binary (/home/owen/install/lib-0.6/src/Relation/Binary.agdai).
```

I'm guessing that the reason it safely "skips" them is that they are already compiled (there are already .agdai files in the directories). But it still spends a lot of time skipping them, and compiles take more than a minute.

Is there a way to avoid all this extra work on every compile?

Comment: by compilation you mean producing an executable or just typechecking?

Comment: @saizan Good question. I suppose just type checking is enough because it is the most repetitive task. though producing an executable is nice too.

Answer (score 1):

Agda has to load at least some of those .agdai files into memory to be able to typecheck your own code, so that might be why even if checking of those modules is skipped it still takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

Agda and other similar software systems like coq have interactive interfaces available, usually through Proof General installed in emacs.

Modular compilation works in other contexts because programming languages tend to rely on shallow name checks for external symbols, if they check at all.  Agda is a proof system, so if it's going to do its job it has to start from scratch every time and deep-verify the entire proof.

Comment: hmmm.... I suppose I'm not exactly looking for modular compilation, I just like running the compiler from the command line separate from the editor; ie since agda can re-type check quickly in emacs, if it could maybe run as a demon... Do you see what I mean?